# Windows 10: auto-delete runs on startup

Tags: windows, windows-10, malware

When my Windows 10 starts, every now and then I see that the "delete file" dialog window runs very briefly. It's way too quick for me to see which file/folder it pertains. This happens right when the desktop first shows after the start up.

Also sometimes, again on startup, I'm seeing a series of cmd windows show up and close really quick. Again too fast too tell what they're about.

Could this be some malware?

Comment: "Could this be some malware?" - Anything is possible.  We would need more information, like what exactly is being launched, automatically.  Autoruns is a great program.

Comment: You can also do a full scan with Windows Defender (on all Windows 10 computers)

Answer (score 0):

You can open Task Manager -> Startup to see your startup programs:

[image: taskmgr.exe]

Select the bad guy and Disable it.

If you don't see it, go to Settings and search for 'startup apps'. See anything you don't recognize?

[image: aaa!!!]

Disable it!